# Função em C que conta quantas vezes a string aparece em um arquivo

Tags: c, funções

Preciso fazer uma função que receba como parâmetros um ponteiro
para uma string e o nome de um arquivo e retorne para o main quantas
vezes a string foi encontrada no arquivo.

eu só consegui fazer com que ela busque a string somente uma vez.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void buscaPalavra();

int main(void) {

  char nomeArquivo[30]= "teste.txt";
  char palavra[30] = "unisinos";
 
  //printf("Digite o nome do arquivo: \n");
  //scanf("%s",nomeArquivo);

  //printf("Digite a palavra que deseja buscar: \n");
  //scanf("%s",palavra);

  buscaPalavra(nomeArquivo,palavra);

  return 0;
}

void buscaPalavra(char *nomeArquivo, char *palavra){

  FILE *arquivo;  
  char conteudo[100];
  int qtd = 0;
  int aux;
  int i;
  int flag;

  if((arquivo = fopen(nomeArquivo,"r")) == NULL){
    printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo\n");
  }

  fgets(conteudo, 98, arquivo);


    for(i=0; i < strlen(conteudo); i++){
      if(conteudo[i]==palavra[0]){
          aux=i;
          flag =1;
        }
      }
      for(int j = 0; j <= strlen(palavra); j++){
        if(palavra[j] == conteudo[aux]){
          aux++;
        } else {
          flag =0;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(flag != 0){
        qtd++;

  }
  fclose(arquivo);
  printf("Total de palavras eh: %d\n",qtd);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, você só chama uma vez `fgets(conteudo, 98, arquivo)`. E se o arquivo tiver mais que 98 caracteres? Sendo assim, você deveria fazer um *loop* e ir lendo até não ter mais o que ler. Algo assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// conta quantas vezes a palavra aparece no arquivo
int contaOcorrencias(char *nomeArquivo, char *palavra){
    char conteudo[100];
    FILE *arquivo = fopen(nomeArquivo, "r");
    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        printf("Erro ao abrir arquivo %s\n", nomeArquivo);
        exit(-1); // se deu erro, sai
    }

    int cont = 0;
    // loop para ir lendo o arquivo
    while (fgets(conteudo, 100, arquivo) != NULL) {
        char *tmp = conteudo;
        while ((tmp = strstr(tmp, palavra)) != NULL) {
            cont++; // encontrei uma ocorrência
            tmp++; // continua a busca a partir da posição seguinte
        }
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
    return cont;
}

int main() {
    // declara o nomeArquivo, palavra, etc...

    // obtém a quantidade de vezes que a palavra ocorre no arquivo
    int ocorrencias = contaOcorrencias(nomeArquivo, palavra);

    // faz o que quiser com o valor (printf, etc)
    printf("A palavra \"%s\" ocorre %d vezes no arquivo %s\n", palavra, ocorrencias, nomeArquivo);

    return 0;
}
```

Vale lembrar que `fgets` lê até o limite de caracteres informado, **ou** até encontrar uma quebra de linha (o que ocorrer primeiro). Geralmente há a preocupação de se remover esta quebra de linha, mas neste caso eu não acho necessário, já que você vai procurar pela palavra, e a quebra de linha no final não irá influenciar na busca (a menos, é claro, que a "palavra" tenha quebras de linha). Também estou assumindo que não há palavras "quebradas" (que houve separação de sílabas e ela continue na linha debaixo, por exemplo).

Depois, eu uso [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr), que verifica se uma string ocorre dentro de outra, e retorna um ponteiro para o caractere onde a ocorrência se inicia (ou `NULL` caso não encontre nada). Eu faço um *loop* pois pode ser que a palavra ocorra mais de uma vez na mesma linha, e conforme encontro, vou atualizando o contador.

---

Vale lembrar que esta abordagem é ingênua, pois se eu procurar por "corro" e no arquivo tiver as palavras "socorro" ou "corrosivo", ambas serão contabilizadas. Se quiser ser mais preciso (considerar apenas a palavra "corro", ignorando os casos em que ela é parte de uma palavra), aí já complica um pouco mais, pois você teria que analisar a frase, verificando se há separadores (espaços, sinais de pontuação, etc).

Uma opção é usar [`strtok`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) para separar a string em partes:

```
// conta quantas vezes a palavra aparece no arquivo
int contaOcorrencias(char *nomeArquivo, char *palavra) {
    char conteudo[100];
    FILE *arquivo = fopen(nomeArquivo, "r");
    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        printf("Erro ao abrir arquivo %s\n", nomeArquivo);
        exit(-1); // se deu erro, sai
    }

    int cont = 0;
    char *delimiters = " ,.-;!?";
    while (fgets(conteudo, 100, arquivo) != NULL) {
        char *tok = strtok(conteudo, delimiters);
        while (tok != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(tok, palavra) == 0)
                cont++;
            tok = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
        }
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
    return cont;
}
```

Como separador eu usei `" ,.-;!?"`, ou seja, ele separa as partes usando espaço, vírgula, ponto ou algum dos outros caracteres (adapte para o seu caso), o que resolve o caso já mencionado em que a palavra a ser buscada é parte de outra palavra maior.

Comment: já tinha tentado com o strstr porem n tinha conseguido, ai eu fiz de outra forma. Mas agora entendi oq foi feito, muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Answer (score -1):

Colocar uma estrutura de repetição na invocação da função `buscaPalavra` força a função a realizar mais de uma busca.